# How can I convert special characters to normal characters in an URL query string?

Tags: 6, uri

`?` and `=` will be used as parts in my url. In generating the url, I use

`<?php echo l('node/'. $someID .'/delete?destination=chapter/'. $anotherID);?>`. When I check on `Firebug`, the `href` attribute of the link is not the usual `url`, instead of having `?`, it is being replaced with `%3F` and `=` is being replaced with `%3D`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Look into the `l()` documentation here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/6 and the underlying `url()` documentation here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/6 to put the `query string` in the `$options` array where it belongs.  Otherwise `l()` is going to mangle it up as you are seeing in its zeal to create a safe link.  You can also investigate `$html` set to `TRUE` there if you want to go your current route.

Answer (score 1):

To generate URL we use [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7.x) function. [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x) function is used to generate a text with link. See the example below:

```
// Generate a Text with link
echo l('Link Text', 'node/' . $nid . '/delete', array('query' => array('destination' => 'chapter/' . $cnid)));

// Generate a Link.
echo url('node/' . $nid . '/delete', array('query' => array('destination' => 'chapter/' . $cnid)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 <?php echo l('/node/'. $someID .'/delete?destination=chapter/'. $anotherID,'/node/'. $someID .'/delete?destination=chapter/'. $anotherID);?>
```

And you will see what Jimajamma is talking about. The first string is converted to special characters to display on the page. The second string becomes the href="" string.